# How do I setup Android SDK for GMS?

Tags: game-maker, windows, android-studio, settings

I am trying to set the path for the [android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) in [GameMaker: Studio](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.yoyogames.com/gamemaker&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwipy57I_bzVAhVR7mMKHeypB0cQFggUMAA&usg=AFQjCNHHo70VL1xMWJRtWtvfEl0RBr5QjA), but I am having an unexpected ammount of difficulty with this. Initialy, I installed Android Studio and tried setting it's directory, but got the `"Cannot find Android SDK in this directory C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"` error. So I tried going deeper into the program's directory but continued to get the error.

I went online and did some research which yielded several different options (none of which worked). The first thing I looked into was [this link](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://forum.yoyogames.com/index.php%3Fthreads/how-to-setup-the-android-sdk.17495/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiy6p3A_7zVAhVN5GMKHU0fBaIQFggYMAE&usg=AFQjCNEY8zpJDwOyYZihM1QmNVwQ1gMAnA) in the YoYo Game's GMS community. Then I tried downloadong all SDK packs in android studio, then moving the SDK folder to:

```
C:\Android\android-sdk
```

This *also* did not work.

I even went through *every single* android related folder and came across three additional "SDK" directories. Again, none of them worked. I even tried downloading an archived version of the SDK that did nothing. I have been attempting to set up my android SDK ***for over an hour!***

Is there something I'm missing here? Do I need to update something? Does Android Studio no longer include the necessary SDK files?

Comment: I actually don't remeber exactly, but I didn't even download the Andorid Studio, you need only SDK, NDK and Java JDK. Official tutorial is here: [GameMaker: Studio Android (SDK and NDK setup)](https://help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/216753498-GameMaker-Studio-Android-SDK-and-NDK-setup-)

Comment: I already came across that page. The link directs me to Android Studio. This is why I am wondering if the SDK is no longer available, or if the studio is _supposed_ to include it. Finding a direct link to a stand-alone SDK is proving to be quite a challenge. I should note that I have successfully set up the Android NDK and java JDK.

Comment: Do you have something reminding similar windows (such as in tutorial) in Android Studio? I suppose you can also Google the location of ASK in AS

Comment: With the official tutorial is enough to do a fine installation, use the command line tools for SDK that is easier.